# Centering checkbox buttons in Bootstrap 4 row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am trying to center checkboxes as buttons in Bootstrap. I've tried using "text-center" and "center-block" within the surrounding div and the input but with no effect. (You can see in the example each of "text-center" and "center-block" used in numerous places.)

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="row grade-selection">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group text-center" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">K</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary text-center">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input class="text-center" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group center-block" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">3</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary center-block">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">4</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row grade-selection">
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input class="center-block" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">5</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
          <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off">6</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
          <input type="checkbox" checked autocomplete="off">7</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">8</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">9</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row grade-selection">
      <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">10</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">11</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">12</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I have created a Fiddle and highlighted the background a different colour for one of the divs so that you can see the lack of centering: 
https://jsfiddle.net/rovh1fcw/3/

Thanks for your help! I'm sure it's something simple I am overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text-center` class is now `text-xs-center` in Bootstrap 4 alpha. Also remove the `btn-group` from your columns as this is causing the button to display inline..

```
<div class="col-xs-2 text-xs-center" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary text-xs-center">
  <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">1</label>
</div>
```

<kbd>**DEMO:** http://www.codeply.com/go/ZjGIIW1qeQ</kbd>

[More on upgrading to Bootstrap 4](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/)

Comment: Perfect! Making those two changes is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
div[data-toggle]{  
   display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rovh1fcw/18/